# incorrect google maps static localization

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am create static maps using Google maps and am getting an odd problem.  I am trying to encode a university around here but Google Maps static appears to create a map for somewhere in Virginia.

The link I am using is:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=10945+BOULEVARD+Circle+near+21117&zoom=l6&size=500x500&markers=color:red%7C10945+BOULEVARD+Circle+near+21117&format=jpeg&maptype=map&sensor=false&

When I go to google maps and just do 10945+BOULEVARD+Circle+near+21117 I get the correct map.  Is this some odd bug in google maps static or am I missing something?

Comment: Where exactly is 10945 Boulevard Circle?  I'm seeing it show up in San Leandro, CA on Google Maps.  Is that the correct city and state?

Comment: Owings Mills MD.  (http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=10945+Boulevard+Circle+21117&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1603&bih=1267&ix=sea&ion=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x89c817008d77b913:0xff88db9098b294ae,10945+Boulevard+Cir,+Owings+Mills,+MD+21117&gl=us&ei=JG41T-THOsrq0QHMhf3cAg&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CB4Q8gEwAA)

Comment: Should have said, too, to note the "near 21117" in the above URL to the static map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use "near" in your address, though if you know the city and state, it's always best to include that in the query.  Looks like the word "circle" in your address is being misinterpreted (e.g., change it to "cir").

I simply changec circle to cir and it works for me:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=10945+BOULEVARD+Cir+Near+21117&zoom=16&size=500x500&markers=color:red%7C10945+BOULEVARD+Cir+near+21117&format=jpeg&maptype=map&sensor=false&

You could also simply add the state abbreviation and remove "near" and it should also work.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful.  But, why does google maps and google maps static show different maps with the same location (at least as far as I can tell). Ie with the "Boulevard+circle" for both?  Are they using a different geolocator/geoencoder?

Comment: It seems if I keep my original one with the "circle" and add "...+near+21117+md..." (ie add the "md") it seems to work also. So it seems it has something to do with the 21117 as well. Weird. But again, thanks.